# Spark get top N highest score results for each (item1, item2, score)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a **DataFrame** of the following format:

```
item_id1: Long, item_id2: Long, similarity_score: Double
```

What I'm trying to do is to get top N highest similarity_score records for each item_id1.
So, for example:

```
1 2 0.5
1 3 0.4
1 4 0.3
2 1 0.5
2 3 0.4
2 4 0.3
```

With top 2 similar items would give:

```
1 2 0.5
1 3 0.4
2 1 0.5
2 3 0.4
```

I vaguely guess that it can be done by first grouping records by item_id1, then sorting in reverse by score and then limiting the results. But I'm stuck with how to implement it in Spark Scala.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use window-functions for this:

```
 df
  .withColumn("rnk",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"item_id1").orderBy($"similarity_score")))
  .where($"rank"<=2)
```

Alternatively, you could use `dense_rank`/`rank` instead of `row_number`, depending on how to handle cases where the similarity-score is equal.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. Need to read more on Window.