# Converting Pandas into Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

So I'm trying to convert my python algorithm to Spark friendly code and I'm having trouble with this one:

```
indexer = recordlinkage.SortedNeighbourhoodIndex \
          (left_on=column1, right_on=column2, window=41)       

pairs = indexer.index(df_1,df_2)
```

It basically compares one column against the other and generates index pairs for those likely to be the same (Record Matching).

My code:

```
df1 = spark.read.load(*.csv)
df2 = spark.read.load(*.csv)

func_udf = udf(index.indexer) ????
df = df.withColumn('column1',func_udf(df1.column1,df2.column2)) ???
```

I've been using udf for transformations involving just one dataframe and one column, but how do I run a function that requires two arguments, one column from one dataframe and other from other dataframe? I can't join both dataframes as they have different lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `udf` work. `UserDefinedFunctions` can operate only on data that comes from a single `DataFrame`

- Standard `udf` on data from a single row.
- `pandas_udf` on data from a single partition or single group.

> I can't join both dataframes as they have different lengths.

Join is exactly what you should do (standard or manual broadcast). There is no need for objects to be of the same length - Spark join is a relational join not row-wise merge.

For similarity joins you can use built-in approx join tools:

- [Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672)
- [Optimize Spark job that has to calculate each to each entry similarity and output top N similar items for each](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50088548)